# 【Flutter/Dart】(Self-produced class)FooDecoration's issue. Container under Container(Column) is not drawn

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-container

I found a class called `FooDecoration` on the internet, and I am using it.
`FooDecoration` replaces `BoxDecoration` of Container.

I am having trouble drawing a Container that exists below a Container to which I have applied `FooDecoration`.

The first image shows the actual situation.
The second image is the ideal form we would like to implement.
image URL

[image]

This code is main class.

```
class ApexTfquiz extends StatelessWidget {


 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    int num = 1;

return Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    gradient: LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        Color.fromRGBO(250, 101, 107, 1).withOpacity(1.0),
        Color.fromRGBO(141, 110, 201, 1).withOpacity(1.0),
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft, //ピンク
      end: Alignment.bottomRight, //紫
    ),
  ),
  child: Column(children: <Widget>[

    Stack(
      children:[
        SizedBox(
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: Scaffold(
            resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                future: getSnapshot(num),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return const Text("エラーが発生しました");
                  }


                  return Center(
                    heightFactor:20,
                    child:Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height:height*0.09,
                      ),
                        Container(
                        child: Container(
                            height: height*0.5,
                            width: width,
                            decoration: FooDecoration(
                              insets: EdgeInsets.only(top:10, bottom:10, left: 10, right: 10),
                              blurRadius: 2,
                            ),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Center(child: Text(snapshot.data!.get('question'))),
                            ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container( //not worked.  why?
                        height:height*0.2,
                        width: width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        child:Text(
                          "aaaaaaa",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                    ),

                  );
                }
                )
        ),
      ),
        AppBar(
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return IconButton(
                splashColor:  Color.fromRGBO(250, 101, 107, 0.5),
                highlightColor: Color.fromRGBO(141, 110, 201, 0.5),
                splashRadius: 25,

                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); },
              );
            },
          ),
          foregroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.85),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,

          toolbarHeight: height * 0.08,
          titleSpacing: 0,
          title: (Text(
            '〇×クイズ',
          )),
        ),
      ]
    )
  ]),
);

  }
```

This one is FooDecoration.

```
class FooDecoration extends Decoration {
  final EdgeInsets insets;
  final Color color;
  final double blurRadius;
  final bool inner;

  FooDecoration({
    this.insets = const EdgeInsets.only(top:10, bottom:10, left: 10, right: 10) ,
    this.color = Colors.black,
    this.blurRadius = 2,
    this.inner = false,
  });
  @override
  BoxPainter createBoxPainter([void Function()? onChanged]) => _FooBoxPainter(insets, color, blurRadius, inner);

}

class _FooBoxPainter extends BoxPainter {
  final EdgeInsets insets;
  final Color color;
  final double blurRadius;
  final bool inner;

  _FooBoxPainter(this.insets, this.color, this.blurRadius, this.inner);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Offset offset, ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    var rect = offset & configuration.size!;
    // Rect rect = const Offset(1.0, 2.0) & const Size(3.0, 4.0);
    canvas.clipRect(rect);
    var paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.outer, blurRadius);

    var path = Path();
    if (inner) {
      path
        ..fillType = PathFillType.evenOdd
        ..addRect(insets.inflateRect(rect))
        ..addRect(rect);
    } else {
      path.addRect(insets.deflateRect(rect));
    }
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }
}
```

I have described Container under Container, but for some reason it is not rendered.

When this is commented out, the Container is drawn correctly.

```
 decoration: FooDecoration(
                              insets: EdgeInsets.only(top:10, bottom:10, left: 10, right: 10),
                              blurRadius: 2,
                            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this action is preventing the other Widgets to be rendered, since it clips the canvas.

```
canvas.clipRect(rect);
```

You can put this action in a [canvas.save](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/save.html) - [canvas.restore](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Canvas/restore.html) action, to prevent the canvas from being affected by the clipRect()

```
canvas.save();
canvas.clipRect(rect);
canvas.restore();
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! i solve it . But why is canvas.~~ necessary?

Comment: It's because the canvas.clipRect(rect) is modifying your canvas, so the second container isn't able to shown. canvas.save() and canvas.restore() is an action chain that when you save, the original state of the canvas is saved, then you can modify the canvas and then use restore to return to the original canvas. The action you use in between can then be draw to the canvas without affecting it.